# I need to skip three rows from the dataframe while loading from a CSV file in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I am loading my CSV file to a data frame and I can do that but I need to skip the starting three lines from the file.

I tried `.option()` command by giving header as true but it is ignoring the only first line.

```
val df = spark.sqlContext.read
    .schema(Myschema)
    .option("header",true)
    .option("delimiter", "|")
    .csv(path)
```

I thought of giving header as 3 lines but I couldn't find the way to do that.

alternative thought: skip those 3 lines from the data frame

Please help me with this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Add a line number field in the csv file and filter the rows whose line number is bigger than 3.

Comment: I see that you delimiter is a `|`. Are you reading a file that looks like what `df.show()` would print? If so, try adding `.option("header", true)` and `.option("comment", "+")`. If not, is there anything that sets these three lines apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic way to handle your problem would be to index the dataframe and filter the indices that are greater than 2.

**Straightforward approach:**

As suggested in another answer, you may try adding an index with `monotonically_increasing_id`.

```scala
df.withColumn("Index",monotonically_increasing_id)
  .filter('Index > 2)
  .drop("Index")
```

Yet, that's only going to work if the first 3 rows are in the first partition. Moreover, as mentioned in the comments, this is the case today but this code may break completely with further versions or spark and that would be very hard to debug. Indeed, the contract in the API is just "The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but not consecutive". It is therefore not very sage to assume that they will always start from zero. There might even be other cases in the current version in which that does not work (I'm not sure though).

To illustrate my first concern, have a look at this:

```scala
scala> spark.range(4).withColumn("Index",monotonically_increasing_id()).show()
+---+----------+
| id|     Index|
+---+----------+
|  0|         0|
|  1|         1|
|  2|8589934592|
|  3|8589934593|
+---+----------+
```

We would only remove two rows...

**Safe approach:**

The previous approach will work most of the time though but to be safe, you can use `zipWithIndex` from the RDD API to get consecutive indices.

```scala
def zipWithIndex(df : DataFrame, name : String) : DataFrame = {
  val rdd = df.rdd.zipWithIndex
    .map{ case (row, i) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ i) }
  val newSchema = df.schema
    .add(StructField(name, LongType, false))
  df.sparkSession.createDataFrame(rdd, newSchema)
}
zipWithIndex(df, "index").where('index > 2).drop("index")
```

We can check that it's safer:

```scala
scala> zipWithIndex(spark.range(4).toDF("id"), "index").show()
+---+-----+
| id|index|
+---+-----+
|  0|    0|
|  1|    1|
|  2|    2|
|  3|    3|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you very much ... Oli!!. Your Safe approach worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this option

```
df.withColumn("Index",monotonically_increasing_id())
        .filter(col("Index") > 2)
        .drop("Index")
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's only going to work if the first 3 rows are in the first partition. Most of the time that will be the case but that's not very safe to assume. Try running this in a shell for instance `spark.range(4).withColumn("Index",monotonically_increasing_id()).show()`

Comment: It is not even guaranteed to work on future versions, whatever the partitions. It works today, (javadoc, emphasis mine : " The **current implementation** puts the partition ID in the upper 31 bits, and the record number within each partition in the lower 33 bits."), but the only contract made by the api is : "The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but not consecutive".

Answer (score -1):

You may try changing wrt to your schema.

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
  val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

  //Read CSV
  val file = sc.textFile("csvfilelocation")

  //Remove first 3 lines
  val data = file.mapPartitionsWithIndex{ (idx, iter) => if (idx == 0) iter.drop(3) else iter }

  //Create RowRDD by mapping each line to the required fields 
  val rowRdd = data.map(x=>Row(x(0), x(1)))

  //create dataframe by calling sqlcontext.createDataframe with rowRdd and your schema   
  val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRdd, schema)
```

Comment: Thanks Deepa... your code is working fine but my requirement also need to remove last two rows. Can you suggest me any blog or information regarding mapPartitionsWithIndex function.

Comment: val partitions = file.getNumPartitions
 and     add this condition after the if condition for idx=0,  else if (idx == partitions - 3) iter.sliding(2).map(_.head)